# Building wheel for py4dgeo (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully. - Error

Tags: python, macos, pip, pyproject.toml

I get this error when trying to install py4dgeo (https://github.com/3dgeo-heidelberg/py4dgeo) and don't know what to do. Thankful for any help!

MacOS

Python 3.9.14

Pip 23.2.1

```
  Building wheel for py4dgeo (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Building wheel for py4dgeo (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [100 lines of output]
```

```
  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  -- Trying 'Ninja' generator
  --------------------------------
  ---------------------------
  ----------------------
  -----------------
  ------------
  -------
  --
  CMake Deprecation Warning at CMakeLists.txt:1 (cmake_minimum_required):
    Compatibility with CMake < 3.5 will be removed from a future version of
    CMake.
  
    Update the VERSION argument <min> value or use a ...<max> suffix to tell
    CMake that the project does not need compatibility with older versions.
  
  Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
  
  CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "Ninja".  CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set.  You probably need to select a different build tool.
  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
  --
  -------
  ------------
  -----------------
  ----------------------
  ---------------------------
  --------------------------------
  -- Trying 'Ninja' generator - failure
  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  
  
  
  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  -- Trying 'Unix Makefiles' generator
  --------------------------------
  ---------------------------
  ----------------------
  -----------------
  ------------
  -------
  --
  CMake Deprecation Warning at CMakeLists.txt:1 (cmake_minimum_required):
    Compatibility with CMake < 3.5 will be removed from a future version of
    CMake.
  
    Update the VERSION argument <min> value or use a ...<max> suffix to tell
    CMake that the project does not need compatibility with older versions.
  
  Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
  
  -- The C compiler identification is unknown
  -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
  -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - failed
  -- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
  -- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc - broken
  CMake Error at /private/var/folders/0h/0ncvw0p13k9g0x96c9qgwv4h0000gn/T/pip-build-env-o4056wdi/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.27/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:67 (message):
    The C compiler
  
      "/usr/bin/cc"
  
    is not able to compile a simple test program.
  
    It fails with the following output:
  
      Change Dir: '/private/var/folders/0h/0ncvw0p13k9g0x96c9qgwv4h0000gn/T/pip-install-iym_72c4/py4dgeo_b885e4a9fd874b1c8207d87c2d235813/_cmake_test_compile/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-oyDeAX'
  
      Run Build Command(s): /private/var/folders/0h/0ncvw0p13k9g0x96c9qgwv4h0000gn/T/pip-build-env-o4056wdi/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cmake/data/bin/cmake -E env VERBOSE=1 /usr/bin/make -f Makefile cmTC_56035/fast
      xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
  
  
  
  
  
    CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
  Call Stack (most recent call first):
    CMakeLists.txt:3 (ENABLE_LANGUAGE)
  
  
  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
  --
  -------
  ------------
  -----------------
  ----------------------
  ---------------------------
  --------------------------------
  -- Trying 'Unix Makefiles' generator - failure
  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  
                  ********************************************************************************
                  scikit-build could not get a working generator for your system. Aborting build.
  
                  Building MacOSX wheels for Python 3.9 requires XCode.
  Get it here:
  
    https://developer.apple.com/xcode/
  
                  ********************************************************************************
  [end of output]
```

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for py4dgeo
Failed to build py4dgeo
ERROR: Could not build wheels for py4dgeo, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Comment: Try running `xcode-select --install`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+xcrun%3A+error%3A+invalid+active+developer+path+missing+xcrun